# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning replace in column

Tags: pandas, copy

I have line:

```py
df[["col_1", "col_2"]].replace(np.nan, "value", inplace = True)
```

And I get warrning:
A value is trying to be set on copy of xlice from DataFrame.

could you explain me why I have that message, and how I can fix it?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: It does not work

Comment: Try this:
`df.loc[:, ["col_1", "col_2"]] = df.loc[:, ["col_1", "col_2"]].replace(np.nan, "value")`